# parallel with quote in command

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, bioinformatics, gnu-parallel

my original input in linux terminal is

---

```
bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' input1.vcf -O v -o output1.filter.vcf
bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' input2.vcf -O v -o output2.filter.vcf    
bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' input3.vcf -O v -o output3.filter.vcf    
bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' input4.vcf -O v -o output4.filter.vcf    
bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' input5.vcf -O v -o output5.filter.vcf
```

---

I already have a file called parallel.input, which contain

---

```
[***@dev1 raw_reads]$ cat parallel.input

input1.vcf
output1.filter.vcf
input2.vcf
output2.filter.vcf
input3.vcf
output3.filter.vcf
input4.vcf
output4.filter.vcf
input5.vcf
output5.filter.vcf
```

---

When I did parallel, with this command

```
cat parallel.input | parallel -j 3 -k --max-args=2 --joblog parallel.log "bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' {1} -O v -o {2}"
```

it got this error

```
[filter.c:2278 filters_init1] Error: the tag "snp" is not defined in the VCF header
[filter.c:2278 filters_init1] Error: the tag "snp" is not defined in the VCF header
[filter.c:2278 filters_init1] Error: the tag "snp" is not defined in the VCF header
[filter.c:2278 filters_init1] Error: the tag "snp" is not defined in the VCF header
[filter.c:2278 filters_init1] Error: the tag "snp" is not defined in the VCF header
```

I think because it has the quote in the bcftools command. But I need the quote as the input

Any idea how to do the parallel?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a function:

```
myfunc() {
  bcftools filter -e 'TYPE="snp"' "$1" -O v -o "$2"
}
export -f myfunc

cat parallel.input |
  parallel -j 3 -k --max-args=2 --joblog parallel.log myfunc
```

Comment: thanks a lot Ole, this helped me a lot! I was struggling for an hour with awk in paralel quote issues